# Custom draw a List component in Flex with AS3

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need a List component that will display custom data. I want to extend a spark List or any List component and add my code to paint each item.
I done this in other frameworks but for Flex i found only simple examples that change the font and background color, i need access to a Graphics object to paint my items as i need,is there a method that i can override or some example /class i should look at?

Comment: My solution was to create a custom component by extending the  UIComponent, overriding the updateDisplayList method ,then i created an ItemRenderer where i used my custom component and a Label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UIComponents has a 'graphics' property that you can draw to, however, I'm not too sure why you'd want to extend the list component just to paint each item.  Each item renderer is responsible for painting itself.  If anything, just use the normal List and specify the itemRenderer property to point to a custom item renderer of your own (that extends ItemRenderer) that can take in data and paint things accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i searched the ItemRenderer and i did not found any example that involved using a Graphics object,if you are sure that is possible with this class i will research more

Comment: No need to look more.  [ItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html) extends UIComponent. It has a graphics property.